# set up a table thing_id field that choose to have relationship with tables base on thing_type

Tags: ruby-on-rails

lets say I have a table call payment that have a field call thing_id that will be the foreign key of buy and storage depend on the thing_type field in payment table.

How do I implement this relationship? In migration file , how do I define the foreign key?
In model file , I should use :through ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but I think you are talking about Polymorphic associations in Rails.

Have a look here: [Railscasts - Polymorphic Association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association)